# Nested loop printing one letter

Tags: python

Ive been trying to make a code generator in python lately. Once you input a word, it'll encode it. But when it prints the new code it only prints 1 random letter. Ive tried using just a while loop and just a for loop but nothing seems to work. The rest of the code works fine but I can't figure out why it only prints one letter. Sorry if this code isnt the best possible way to about it. Im pretty new to this sort of stuff!

```
import random
letters_lower = ("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f")

def encode():
    new_code = ""
    user_code = input("What would you like to encode? ")
    for letters in user_code:
        while user_code > new_code:
            new_code + (random.choice(letters_lower))
    print(new_code)
```

Comment: `new_code + (random.choice(letters_lower))` This does some concatenation and then throws away the result. You should assign the result to some variable or do something with it.

Comment: I think you mean `new_code += (random.choice(letters_lower))`. 
The while loop shouldn't be necessary.  This isn't much of an encoding though, as its not deterministic,.

Comment: `while user_code > new_code:` what do you think this does?

Comment: "it [...] prints one letter." does it, though?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Inside your `encode()` function, inside the `while` loop, you are not assigning the concatenation to any variable and the while loop therefore do nothing. You need to assign in to a new variable or updating it (i.e., `new_code = new_code + ...` or equivalently `new_code += ...` ) to be used later on when you return the output of your function.

```
import random
letters_lower = ("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f")

def encode():
    new_code = ""
    user_code = input("What would you like to encode? ")
    for letters in user_code:
        while user_code > new_code:
            new_code = new_code + (random.choice(letters_lower))
    print(new_code)

new_code = encode()
```

Comment: Maybe using `+=` would be better than `new_code = new_code + (random.choice(letters_lower))`. Also some explanation for op would be useful.